# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379[nodemon app crashed]

Tags: redis

Hi I’m working on a typescript project(express, PostgreSQL) on m1  and I installed Redis to yarn and started the local server (nodemon) and the error was happen. Before I implemented the Redis to my project that’s not an issue.

**Here is error**

```
> % yarn dev2 
yarn run v1.22.10
$ nodemon --exec ts-node src/index.ts
[nodemon] 2.0.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: ts,json
[nodemon] starting `ts-node src/index.ts`
[discovery] ORM entity discovery started, using ReflectMetadataProvider
[discovery] - processing entity Post
[discovery] - processing entity User
[discovery] - entity discovery finished, found 2 entities, took 13 ms
[info] MikroORM successfully connected to database postgres on postgresql://postgres@127.0.0.1:5432
[query] select table_name, nullif(table_schema, 'public') as schema_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema not like 'pg_%' and table_schema != 'information_schema' and table_name != 'geometry_columns' and table_name != 'spatial_ref_sys' and table_type != 'VIEW' order by table_name [took 18 ms]
[query] begin
[query] select * from "mikro_orm_migrations" order by "id" asc [took 3 ms]
[query] commit
server started on localhost:4000
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I want to know

- how to debug on Redis in this situation?

**My environments**

- Vscode
- npm -7.5.3
- Node -v14.15.4
- Homebrew 3.0.1(arm)

Answer (score 0):

1. reinstall redis on homebrew
2. redis server
3. yarn dev
4. worked

This [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754304/redis-connection-to-127-0-0-16379-failed-connect-econnrefused) might be helpful